# NSConstraint not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

I have a toolbar with a `UIImageView` I added programmatically. When I tried adding `NSConstraint` to the `UIImageView` to center it in the toolbar view. When I ran it on the simulator, it crashed.
Here's my code:

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
                 nav.frame.size.width, nav.frame.size.height)];

image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageTop objectAtIndex:2]];
[imageToolbar addSubview:image];

[imageToolbar addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:image
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                   toItem:imageToolbar
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                  multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

[imageToolbar addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:image
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                   toItem:imageToolbar
                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                  multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];
```

Error:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this:

(1) Look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;

(2) Find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing `NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints` that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the `UIView` property `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`)

(

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcfc2536f50 UIImageView:0x7fcfc2536d50.centerX == UIToolbar:0x7fcfc2525610.centerX>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcfc252dad0 UIView:0x7fcfc252c750.trailingMargin == UIToolbar:0x7fcfc2525610.trailing - 16>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcfc252db20 UIToolbar:0x7fcfc2525610.leading == UIView:0x7fcfc252c750.leadingMargin - 16>",

"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fcfc254fea0 h=--& v=--& UIImageView:0x7fcfc2536d50.midX == + 160>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcfc2551110 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fcfc252c750(375)]>"
```

)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fcfc2536f50 UIImageView:0x7fcfc2536d50.centerX == UIToolbar:0x7fcfc2525610.centerX>
```

Make a symbolic breakpoint at `UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints` to catch this in the debugger.

The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: And when it crashed it gave you a very important message in the console, which said...?

Comment: So you didn't bother to _read_ the crash log, you didn't bother to _post_ the crash log, and you posted the wrong code. Unfortunately I can only downvote a question once. It's good that you've fixed those things now, though. Next time, please fix them _before_ you post.

Answer (score 0):

You have created an UIImageView but you have not added that image view to the interface. You cannot add constraints for a view that is not in the interface. If you do, you will, uh, crash.

Also, you have neglected to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to NO. If you neglect to do that, then when you add your own constraints, you will have a constraint conflict and you will, uh, crash.

Really, it's just a matter of reading the error message in the console. As my old folk dancing teacher used to say, "The music tells you what to do!"

Comment: I did add the imageView in the toolbar. I didn't post it tho

Comment: To post code that is not in fact your code is foolish and rude. People cannot help you if you lie about what your code says. However, I've answered the question anyway.

Comment: I just did not post in stackoverflow, I just updated it. Sorry for the confusion